# How to prevent unintended selection by SelectionTracker when toolbar drops down?

Tags: android, user-interface

When I long-click on an item in my `RecyclerView` to select it (i.e., select the initial item in the selection list managed by `SelectionTracker`), an `ActionView` expands at the top of the display screen and forces all other `Views` downward a distance equal to the `ActionView's` height.  This is desired behavior.

However, if the y-coordinate of the long-press is within a distance equal to the `ActionView's` height from the top of the item's `View`, then the item above that item will also be selected, which is not desirable. This is happening because, after the downward translation of all `Views`, the `SelectionTracker` sees that other item as being under the long-press coordinates and automatically determines that it, too, should be selected. This is equivalent to the user having immediately dragged the pointer up a distance equal to the `ActionView's` height had the `ActionView` not appeared.

There are two approaches I've thought of to deal with this problem:

The first involves intercepting the click and translating its y-coordinate down a distance equal to the height of the expanded `ActionView`, but only under the right conditions (i.e., only when there are no existing selections and only if the clicked-on item is not at position 0 in the adapter).  There are several problems with this approach, but I was curious to see if it would work.  (It didn't.)  One class of problems centers around how to get the same coordinates that `SelectionTracker` uses.  These are coordinates within the `RecyclerView's` local coordinate system (aka: "View coordinates"), but there's no way to get to them through the `SelectionTracker` API.  They are, however, used by the `ItemDetails` lookup's `getItemDetails(MotionEvent)` method. Unfortunately, modifying the coordinates of the input `MotionEvent` has no "downstream" effect on the selection/non-selection of subsequent items.

The second approach was to write a custom `SelectionPredicate`. I believe this would work to prevent the selection of the second item, because I think the selection logic within `SelectionTracker` is subject to the logic within the `SelectionPredicate`.  However, the problem I'm having with this approach is, again, getting access to the coordinates used internally by the `SelectionTracker`. With those coordinates, I could determine when the conditions exist that would result in the unwanted, automatic selection of that second item and, therefore, I could return false from the `SelectionPredicate` callbacks where appropriate.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to address this problem?

Comment: Neither TouchInputHelper nor GestureSelectionHelper can be subclassed, since they are both final.

Comment: Was able to get a subclass of SelectionPredicate to "do the right thing."  However, learned that, once canSetStateForKey(key, nextState) is invoked for a given list item, it is never invoked again for the current selection session.  Thus, while I was able to prevent the automatic selection of the item above the actual selected item when the ActionView expanded, I was never able to intentionally select that item, either with a discrete selection action or a continuous selection action. Therefore, have decided the automatic, unwanted selection of the other item is the lesser of the two evils.